# The name 'Sitecore' does not exist in the current context

Tags: visual-studio, build, compiler-errors, namespaces, sitecore

I have a new instance of Sitecore 9. I'm trying to create my first component, an ascx file with a codebehind file, and I have this line:

```
var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
```

The build is failing with the error "The name 'Sitecore' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1):

please make sure that you have added the reference to "Sitecore.Kernel.dll". i would suggest you to also checkout the nuget packages provided from Sitecore:

[Sitecore Nuget Feeds](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_public_nuget_packages_faq)

Depending on your deployment Strategy it would be a good practice to use the nuget. Sitecore has created every nuget package with ".NoReferences" extension for example : "Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences" which is great for dependency management.
If you are using MVC you will need also "Sitecore.Mvc.dll".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a error specification in the output window for this error which turned out to be an hint to solve this error.

The .NET framework version of my visual studio project was targeted at v4.6.1, **updating the project's target framework to v4.6.2 fixed my error** : "The name 'Sitecore' does not exist in the current context"!

**It seems that the Sitecore.kernel.dll (responsible for using term 'Sitecore' for reference in code like controllers) with version 11.1.0.0 was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" (of my visual studio project).**

Here is the error specification (hint!) in my VS output window that I mentioned earlier:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "Sitecore.Kernel, Version=11.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1".
```